# exePath must be specified when not running inside a stand alone exe

Tags: c#, web-config, app-config

When i am using a web application, the line of code below

```
Configuration objConfig = 
    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration( ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

in class library are giving this error:

> "exePath must be specified when not running inside a stand alone exe."

Previously a console application was being used, and the code could access the `app.config`. I tried using the `System.Web.Configuration` in class library but the dll was not present in the .Net tab for "Add reference".

Kindly help :)

Comment: What version of the .NET Framework are you using?

Comment: @wgraham The web application is in .net 4.0 and the class libraries are in 3.5

Comment: Is this a class library you have the source to, or is it a third party library?

Answer (score 52):

You need to use a different configuration manager in a web context.  The following code 
block shows an example of how to deal with this:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = null;         
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
{
   configuration =
       System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
}
else
{
  configuration =
      ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
}
```

Comment: I believe "~" should be "~/" ("~" did not work for me)

Comment: I can't believe this is so sucky.  I absolutely don't want to reference System.Web where I'm doing this.

Comment: There are situations where `HttpContent` is null, but you still need to call `WebConfigurationManager` such as tasks which actually run in a separate thread, e.g., `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're doing; but at first glance it looks like you're trying to use code written for a WinForms application in a web environment.  This almost certainly will not work, since your web app won't have the permissions you need.
Try looking up how to do this in a web environment (since you seem to be dealing with config files, try searching on WEB.CONFIG to start)

Comment: This got me on the right track to solve the issue I was having. I was missing some sections in my web.config

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the answer from @shane but ended up with the same exception using Hangfire. This code worked for me though:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration configFile = null;
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
{
    configFile =
        System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
}
else
{
    System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = $"{System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}Web.Config" };
    configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
}
```

**Note that editing Web.config will cause the application pool to restart**!

Comment: Yes, opening the Web.config like that is not a good idea!  There must be a better way

Comment: @JeremyRayBrown Opening Web.config in a running application is never good. If a value is edited the web application will reboot. This is a last option solution.

Comment: I adjusted my code to only do this at start up.  My application must support plugging in unknown dlls and appSettings at runtime.  But, the app pool will only recycle once, best I could do.