# exePath exception when using SAP .net connector 3.0 in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, sap-dotnet-connector

Have a WPF app that I am converting to ASP.net and I am having issues with SAP.

When I run this line I get an exception.

```
RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(Backend);
```

Exception Message `{"exePath must be specified when not running inside a stand alone exe."}`

Stack Trace

> at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfigurationImpl(ConfigurationFileMap fileMap, Boolean isMachine, ConfigurationUserLevel userLevel, String exePath, Boolean preLoad)
>      at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel userLevel)
>      at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcConfigParameters..cctor()

googling around I saw as similar issue here [exePath must be specified when not running inside a stand alone exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720576/exepath-must-be-specified-when-not-running-inside-a-stand-alone-exe)

The issue seems to be using `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration` rather that `System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager`which is what I need to use. Problem is I can't change that as its part of the SAP.Net Connector.

Is there anything I can do?

Edit: My BackendConfig code

```
public class BackendConfig : IDestinationConfiguration
{
    public RfcConfigParameters GetParameters(String destinationName)
    {
        if ("P38".Equals(destinationName))
        {
            var parms = new RfcConfigParameters
            {
                {RfcConfigParameters.AppServerHost, "SAPSERVER"},
                {RfcConfigParameters.SystemNumber, "86"},
                {RfcConfigParameters.SncMode, "1"},
                {RfcConfigParameters.SncPartnerName, "p:SAP@SERVER"},
                {RfcConfigParameters.Client, "010"},
                {RfcConfigParameters.Language, "EN"},
                {RfcConfigParameters.PoolSize, "5"}
            };
            return parms;
        }           
        else return null;
    }


    // The following two are not used in this example:
    public bool ChangeEventsSupported()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public event RfcDestinationManager.ConfigurationChangeHandler ConfigurationChanged;
}
```

Comment: Is that the complete stack trace?

Comment: Its a stack trace from the most inner exception. One above it says `   at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcConfigParameters.Initialize()
   at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcDestinationManager..cctor()`